# How to set required POST parameters for routes

Tags: 8, routes

With GET method we can do something like this

```
example.user
  path: 'example/{user}'
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content' 
    user: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

so it sets `user` param as required and also limits its format.

But I'd like to do something similar with POST method. Tried this, but not working:

```
example.user
  path: 'example'
  methods:  [POST]
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content' 
    user: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

EDIT:

Sure I can set some logic inside controller like this, but it doesn't feel right:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   $params = json_decode($request->getContent(), TRUE);
   //I'm trying to avoid using these conditions inside controller methods
   if(empty($params['user'])){
      //return error response
   }else{
     if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $params['user'])) {
       //return error response
     }
   }
  //return success response
}
```

So what's drupal way to do it?

Comment: The Drupal way to do a restful interface (noticed "rest" tag in question) is to use RestResource (see EntityResource::post). In other words, use Serializer component to denormalize. If this isn't rest, then maybe we should remove the rest tag?

Comment: @mradcliffe Yeah thanks for heads up about the tag. Now when I read it few times again I think it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal routing system only validates parameters passed via URL (or GET) using route placeholder. [Read more here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/validate-route-parameters)

For a POST method, you can validate parameters on your controller function or if you don't want to pass the request to your controller prior to validating it, technically you can validate the parameters by defining a custom function under the requirement.

```
  example.user
  path: '/example/name'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::access'
```

Then

```
namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Builds an example page.
 */
class ExampleController {

  /**
   * Checks access for a specific request.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    // parameters from the route and/or request as needed.   
   // **Here you can access and validate parameters.**
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->hasPermission('do example things') && $this->someOtherCustomCondition());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before ( take a look at [helper link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2150267) ),it  not required to tell router about type

just post your data and in your controller  get them with

```
$value = \Drupal::request()->request->get('your_posted_variable');
```

Also you can get all $_POST variables with

```
  \Drupal::request()->request->all(); // equal to $_POST
```

Comment: It's true what you are saying, thanks, but I know how to get params. I'm just trying to set them as required. Please see my update, I'm sorry I wasn't more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set anything on the route if you have a default parameter for POST you can add the value directly in the controller:

```
\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content
```

Then you check if you have receive some value in the POST method and if you have values replace the default value.